Yocto adding patch in custom layer

Created a new custom layer named meta-mylayer
Assigned Priority 6
Added patches to folder meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging/XXX-evm
Added patches entry in meta-mylayer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-ti-staging_%.bbappend
Compile code, bitbake -C compile  linux-ti-staging

Compilation fails while Patching, when BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-mylayer = "6" but
when BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-mylayer = "16" patching & compilation succeeds.
bitbake -e linux-ti-staging | grep ^SRC_URI
List patching sequence.
when BBFILE_PRIORITY=6 patches in meta-mylayer are applied first.
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-mylayer = "16" meta-mylayer Patches are applied in the end.
In my understanding ** higher numeric value represents a higher priority**, in that case why
BBFILE_PRIORITY_meta-mylayer = "16" Patches are applied in the end?
